# How to add a price fieldset magento 2

Tags: magento2, module

How to add the price indicator to the custom field in Magento?

I am developing a form to add additional attributes to the product. now I am searching for this functionality for a while, can you help me how to add an icon here?

like this. [image]

```
    $fieldset->addField(
        'amount',
        'text',
        [
            'name' => 'amount',
            'label' => __('Material Price'),
            'id' => 'amount',
            'title' => __('Material Price'),
            'class' => 'required-entry validate-zero-or-greater validate-number',
            'required' => true,
        ]
    );
```